# How to get rotaion matrix or quaternion?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, motion-planning, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am doing some arm planning about my robot. I have a point B(x2,y2,z2) in space where I want the end-effector A(x1,y1,z1) to go.

In my opinion, I had better get the quaternion of point B first, then get the IK using point B and quaternion, after that I can use  arm_navigation_msgs::GetMotionPlan to do a plan.

but I am unsure how to produce the quaternions.

or any other good method to plan end-effector from A to B?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198043/how-to-get-rotaion-matrix-or-quaternion?/) by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

May be this [link](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/tf/html/c++/namespacetf.html#a6a6f5f52bc58abac88b795696a2a488a) will be helpful. You will have to use createquaternion function in tf namespace.

---

Originally posted by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) with karma: 72 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-11-23**:
Thank you very much, I will try.

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-11-23**:
I saw function:
static tf::Quaternion tf::createQuaternionFromRPY   (   double      roll,
double      pitch,
double      yaw
)           [inline, static]
I need first get roll, pitch, yaw, do you think there is a function in ROS which I can get roll, pitch ,yaw? Thank you

**Comment by [karen0603](https://answers.ros.org/users/5106/karen0603/) on 2014-11-23**:
Thanks for your answer.  This [link text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149670/determining-yaw-pitch-and-roll) is helpful. I have to get roll,pitch,yaw at the point B first, and then use the function what you have suggested to get quaternion.